# Android hashmap for bad order

Tags: android, hashmap

Hello there Stack overflowers
I have problem with my hashmap foreach order in android. i have:

```
    hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("aaaa","aaaa");
    hm.put("bbbb","bbbb");
    hm.put("cccc","cccc");
    return hm;
```

and now i do foreach of this hashmap :

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashmap.entrySet()){
        try{
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),key+" "+ value + " "+,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```

And it toast me in reverse order so :cccc cccc , bbbb bbbb, aaaa aaaa. What i must do to have my toast in good oreder ? Greetings

Comment: HashMap has no notion of oder

Comment: i want t ohave my toast like : aaaa aaaa , bbbb bbbb , cccc cccc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3605320/1638739

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of values retrieved from a HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144776/order-of-values-retrieved-from-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the key in sorted order use TreeMap

```
TreeMap<String, String> hm = new TreeMap<>();
hm.put("aaaa", "aaaa");
hm.put("bbbb", "bbbb");
hm.put("cccc", "cccc");
for (String key : hm.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + "  " + hm.get(key));
}
```